# Почему bind принимает последнее значение переменной цикла?

Tags: javascript, html, функции, foreach, bind

Не понимаю, как сделать, чтобы при клике на кнопки выводилось соответствующее значение, а не последнее. Bind должен остаться и перезапись window тоже

```js
    const buttonsNames = ["create", "delete", "click"];

    const showName = (name) => {
        console.log(name);
    }

    buttonsNames.forEach((el) => {
        window.my = {showName: showName.bind(this, el)};
        document.body.innerHTML += `<button onclick="my.showName()">${el}</button>`;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Строчкой `window.my = {showName: showName.bind(this, el)};` вы постоянно заменяете значение `window.my` на новое. По итогу там будет содержаться только последнее значение.

Попробуйте использовать создание DOM элемента и задание ему свойств динамически вместо добавления этементов в виде статического HTML.

```js
    const buttonsNames = ["create", "delete", "click"];

    const showName = (name) => {
        console.log(name);
    }

    buttonsNames.forEach((el) => {
        var btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.onclick = showName.bind(this, el);
        btn.innerText = el;
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Подходит в качестве решения в определенных случаях:

```js
    const buttonsNames = ["create", "delete", "click"];

    const showName = (name) => {
        console.log(name);
    }

    buttonsNames.forEach((el) => {
        document.body.innerHTML += `<button onclick="showName(this.textContent)">${el}</button>`;
    });
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]